Which approach is better for updating server-side data in a PrimeNG editable table: built-in methods or custom logic?
I’m using a PrimeNG editable table and need to update server-side data when saving a row. I’m considering two approaches:

Built-in methods (pSaveEditableRow and onRowEditSave):
Easy to use but unsure how to handle server errors effectively.

Custom logic with this.table.saveRowEdit():
Provides more control, like keeping the row in edit mode on server update failure.


Which approach is better for ensuring data consistency and handling errors? Are there significant trade-offs between the two?
